# Finding Growth in Dataframe in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have the following data frame

```
Website <- rep(paste("Website",1:3),2)
Year <- c(rep(2013,3),rep(2014,3))
V1 <- c(10,20,50,20,30,70)
V2 <- c(5,15,30,15,30,45)
df <- data.frame(Website,Year,V1,V2)
df


    Website Year V1 V2
1 Website 1 2013 10  5
2 Website 2 2013 20 15
3 Website 3 2013 50 30
4 Website 1 2014 20 15
5 Website 2 2014 30 30
6 Website 3 2014 70 45
```

What I want to find is the growth for each `website` from year `2013` to `2014` i.e. (x1  - x0)/x0 for both variables. This would result in a data frame that does the following

```
    Website  V1  V2
1 Website 1 1.0 2.0
2 Website 2 0.5 1.0
3 Website 3 0.4 0.5
```

This is just the growth rates for each `Website` for both variables, `V1` and `V2`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming that you have more years, `dplyr` handles it beautifully.

```
library(dplyr)
growth <- function(x)x/lag(x)-1
df %>% 
  group_by(Website) %>% 
  mutate_each(funs(growth), V1, V2)
#    Website Year  V1  V2
#1 Website 1 2013  NA  NA
#2 Website 2 2013  NA  NA
#3 Website 3 2013  NA  NA
#4 Website 1 2014 1.0 2.0
#5 Website 2 2014 0.5 1.0
#6 Website 3 2014 0.4 0.5
```

Answer (score 3):

A `data.table` option (I am using [`data.table_1.9.5`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/) that introduced the function `shift`).  Assuming that the year column is "ordered", convert the "data.frame" to "data.table" using `setDT`, loop through the columns ("V1", "V2") with `lapply` (specify the columns in `.SDcols`) and do the calculation for individual columns (`x/shift(x)...`). The default setting for `shift` is `type='lag'` and `n=1L`.  If you want to remove the NA rows, you can use `na.omit` which is also fast in the devel version.

```
library(data.table)
na.omit(setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, function(x)
              x/shift(x) - 1), by=Website, .SDcols=3:4])
#     Website  V1  V2
#1: Website 1 1.0 2.0
#2: Website 2 0.5 1.0
#3: Website 3 0.4 0.5
```